# Total contribution of feature using SHAP values in multi-output regression problem

Tags: neural-networks, feature-selection, shapley-value

I am interested in using SHAP values to perform wrapper-based feature selection.

The model has 3 outputs, and I do have SHAP values for each output, using GradientExplainer, but even after a bit of research, I just couldn't find a proper resource for determining the total level of 'contribution' by each feature in the case of multi-output regressor.

Here is a sample plot that I have, each of which shows the SHAP values for an output element.
[image]

Possible approaches that my dumb mind has are :

1. Calculate the euclidean distance of the shap values for each feature (e.g, each feature will have 3 elements corresponding to the dimension of the output), and determine the level of contribution by looking at the magnitude?
2. Somehow instead of using the model itself, use the MSE error calculator, and let the explainer figure out the level of contribution of each feature to the MSE error, not the output. Unsure how it is possible to code it using the existing libraries, but oh well..

If anyone has anything to say, please do so. Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!